# Is it always worth checking for null pointers?

Tags: android

Let's say we call a method on a variable fetched through `findViewById()`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText("Some text");
```

Android Studio automatically warns us that setText() may produce a `NullPointerException` if `tv` turns out to be `null`. If we however are certain that `tv` will never be `null` (unless something really wonky happens which should crash the app anyway), is it really worth encapsulating the method call within an `if(tv != null){}` statement? What if these two (or more) rows are executed very often? Can we gain any significant performance increase?

Comment: Does `if(TV==null) throw new AssertionError` make the compiler happy?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think there is much point in checking these are `null` because you will know if they are present in your layout file or not, so I wouldn't bother.

However, I do sometimes use the following to prevent the warnings in Android Studio:

```
assert tv != null;
```

I don't know how this affects performance but I imagine it will have almost no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing or creating new exceptions will definitely consume more resources than what you might expect **BUT** it is always good to handle the exception where necessary rather than let the app crash. **IF** you are absolutely certain that the textview or whatever UI element **IS**present in the correct XML for your activity and/or the fragment then i don't think that you should use try catches at all..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use asserts to avoid warning of Android Studio as mentioned above, and with respect to performance I don't think you will notice any huge performance variation. However, its always good to catch exceptions and log them as it can be really useful while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it can be `null`.

If you have complicated layout, and many ids, it can happen if you type id of other layouts.

This is only a warning. If your layout is simple to remember all ids or you sure it's never `null`, don't bother this warning.

This warning is  helpful when you change an id in layout manually.

EX:

layout 1 has ids : **text_view_1**, button_1

layout 2 has ids : **text_view_1**, button_2

Activity 2 use layout 2 and findViewById(**text_view_1**)

If you change from **text_view_1** to **text_view_2** (MANUALLY by typing). No error happened, because id text_view_1 is still exits. But `NullPointerException` will occur when you run application.